# Did something change during Season 3 and Season 4 of Mike Tyson Mysteries?

Tags: mike-tyson-mysteries

Watching Season 4 episodes of Mike Tyson Mysteries, I've noticed that the energy from the characters is lacking and the episodes do not feel the same as the previous 3 seasons. There seems to be a bit more tension between the team and I've also noticed more aggression towards Deezy as a character with the latest episode being that he was severely injured in a car accident, but there was a very weak punch line to it, trying to make it funny.

Did something happen between season 3 and season 4? Writer changes or something with the actors or is the show just going in a different direction?

Comment: With regard to the Close vote, the question is NOT opinion based. My question can be either answered with a definitive yes, no or there is no information available. You may be referring to my reason for asking the question which yes, would be opinion based.